# jquery click event executes multiple times in single click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a template file which gets dynamically included inside two or more `DIV` in single page:
divs will be AS below :
                  1. VIEW div
                  2. EDIT div
               other can be - RESOLUTION div ...

EDIT div is `display none` while VIEW div appear and reversal. so, only one can be appear at a time.

template file contains below javascript:

```
   AJS.$(document).on('click', '#addROW', function()
   {
      console.log('calling');
      ....
      ..
   }
```

now, when i click on `add` button (existed in template file) then it executes above event and it should add a single row and print a log message but, it executes doubles so, initially executes two times (as template included in two screens) and prints two times message 'calling' and after some times, it gets double 4 times executes. I expect it should executes one time only and prints 'calling' message once only.

How can i resolve this issue.

It looks like due to javascript is added multiple times.. but how can i control to add it single times into the page or any other way to resolve this issue ?

Thank You

Comment: Put this on jsFiddle so we can check whats going ..

Comment: underscore.js has `_.debounce(yourFunction)` for this issue.  There is also a `_.once(yourFunction)` and a `_.throttle(yourFunction)`.  Code is available (MIT-license), usually pretty short:  http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the script is setted or not for assign new event :

```
AJS.$(document).on('click', '#addROW', function (event) {
    if (event.handled !== true) {
        //put your code here
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This would allow only one time to be inserted.When you click the add button next time it won't work.

Comment: thanks. it works every time on both screen. before that followed - `AJS.$(document).off('click').on('click', '#finalremove', function(){...}` it also works but broke other events calling.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
AJS.$(document).on('click', '#addROW', function(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('calling');
  ....
  ..
}
```